# batch create html colored versions of a list of files reflecting syntax highlighting

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I would like to be able to easily create html-colored versions of a list of files (ex: "all the files in this directory",  or "this list of files")

I know that I can do this manually, one by one, by:

1. opening the file (ex: `:e /path/to/Foo.bash`) in vim (with syntax enabled)
2. typing `:hardcopy` to obtain a html-version of the file that also contains the syntax highlighting colors
3. saving that file (ex: `:w /path/to/Foo.bash.htm`)

But how can I "automate" this, ie do it for either all files in a directory or for a list of comma separated file names ?

Comment: I will need to edit my question as I mixed html version and the command to just print ^^ I need the html versions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a script named `2html` that comes with recent versions of Vim.  Its purpose is to convert files to HTML (see `:h 2html.vim`).  You can run it in a batch like this:

- open all files you want to convert:

  ```
  vim *.sh
  ```
- run the script with a `bufdo`:

  ```
  :bufdo runtime! syntax/2html.vim | wq
  ```

This should create a file `foo.sh.html` for each input file `foo.sh`.  Beware that the script converts files in the exact state they are in Vim: the same color theme is used, closed folders are kept closed etc.

Comment: thanks, i ll try that shorty but it is probably what I needed (and very flexible as I can use the command line to give the list of files, and have the .htm is each respective directories!)

Comment: works like a charm! (I just need to understand why it saves under the ".html" name instead of the original ones like "wq" should do ^^ .... the 2html.vim script also changes the "current filename" ? neat!

Comment: a side effect: if I do `vim  thisdir/*` as step 1, when it saves the .html versions they get added to the list to work on, so it loops ! ( ex:  if there are 2 files (A.sh, B.pl) it does them but they go on to "A.sh.html", then "B.pl.html", etc...

Comment: Which is why you shouldn't do that.  This is what `:h :bufdo` has to say about it: _{cmd} must not delete buffers or add buffers to the buffer list._ The initial command is not adding to the buffer list because the new files `<mumble>.html` don't match `*.sh`. So, careful there.